# How to sync file deletions and directory creations to USB drive?

Tags: python, usb, usb-drive, fsync

I'm writing a Python program, which does various file modifications on USB drive (actually a mounted CircuitPython device). I'd like to minimize the likelihood of problems when user unplugs or resets the device without properly ejecting it first.

When writing a file, I'm [advised to do `fsync` on the open file](https://atom.io/packages/fsync-on-save) before closing it.

How can I ensure similar immediate synchronization on file deletions and directory creations? I don't mind calling an operation system command for this.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `inotify` but it's available only on the Linux platform. You can monitor filesystem events and react on them https://pypi.org/project/inotify/

Comment: For Windows this might be a good starting point: https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html